# Make console title bar display the value of a variable

Tags: c++, variables, console, title

I'm working on a small program that counts up to a number given by the user. The number they enter is stored in the variable `limit`. I want the number in that variable to be displayed in the title kind of like this: "Counting up to 3000" or "Limit set to 3000" or something like that. I've tried using `SetConsoleTitle(limit);` and other things but they just don't work. With the code that I have posted bellow, I get the following error:

> argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015 if that's important in any way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>        
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    begin:                            
    int limit;
    cout << "Enter a number you would like to count up to and press any key to start" << endl;
    cin >> limit;

    SetConsoleTitle(limit); // This is my problem
    int x = 0;
    while (x >= 0)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
        x++;

        if (x == limit) 
        {
            cout << "Reached limit of " << limit << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            goto begin;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SetConsoleTitle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function expects a string as its argument, but you're giving it an integer. One possible solution would be to use [std::to_wstring()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) to convert an integer to a wide-character string. C++ string that you get as a result has a different format from the null-terminated wide-character string that *SetConsoleTitle()* expects, so we need to make the necessary conversion using the [c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method. So, instead of

```
SetConsoleTitle(limit);
```

you should have

```
SetConsoleTitle(to_wstring(limit).c_str());
```

Don't forget to `#include <string>` for *to_wstring()* to work.

If you want a title that includes more than just a number, you'll need to use a string stream (a [wide character string stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/wstringstream/) in this case):

```
wstringstream titleStream;
titleStream << "Counting to " << limit << " goes here";
SetConsoleTitle(titleStream.str().c_str());
```

For string streams to work, `#include <sstream>`. Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>     
using namespace std;

int main()
{
begin:
    int limit;
    cout << "Enter a number you would like to count up to and press any key to start" << endl;
    cin >> limit;

    wstringstream titleStream;
    titleStream << "Counting to " << limit << " goes here";
    SetConsoleTitle(titleStream.str().c_str());
    int x = 0;
    while (x >= 0)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
        x++;

        if (x == limit)
        {
            cout << "Reached limit of " << limit << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            goto begin;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! But can you also add words before the integer? So it would look like "Counting to *integer goes here*"

Comment: I tried SetConsoleTitle(to_wstring("Counting to " limit).c_str());

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!